# Creating QWidget class and inserting it in an QFormLayout looses alignment

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I want a simple widget which contains a QLineEdit, a QPushButton and a second QLineEdit to enter a directory and file name. I started by defining everything within the same QWidget, named `CentralWidget` that I wanted to add as the central widget of a `QMainWindow`. But putting everything in the same object impacts rapidly code readability, so for once, I wanted to split my GUI into multiple simpler widget that would be arranged together.

But when I do that, the alignment in the `QFormLayout` is lost.

MWE: First, the version "working", but with everything in the same object.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRegExp
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QLineEdit,
    QFormLayout,
    QWidget,
    QPushButton,
    QGridLayout,
    QStyle,
)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QRegExpValidator


class CentralWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setObjectName("central_widget")

        # create central widget layout
        layout = QFormLayout()

        layout_dir = QGridLayout()
        line = QLineEdit(objectName="QLineEdit_dir")
        button = QPushButton("", objectName="QPushButton_dir")
        button.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_DialogOpenButton))
        layout_dir.addWidget(line, 0, 0, 1, 5)
        layout_dir.addWidget(button, 0, 6, 1, 1)
        layout.addRow("Directory:", layout_dir)

        validator = QRegExpValidator(QRegExp(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,8}$"))
        line = QLineEdit(maxLength=8, objectName="QLineEdit_fname")
        line.setValidator(validator)
        layout.addRow("File name:", line)
        self.setLayout(layout)


app = QApplication([])
window = CentralWidget()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

[image]

And now the version with the directory part split in a second widget:

```
from pathlib import Path

from PyQt5.QtCore import QRegExp
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QLineEdit,
    QFormLayout,
    QWidget,
    QPushButton,
    QGridLayout,
    QStyle,
    QFileDialog,
)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QRegExpValidator


class CentralWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setObjectName("central_widget")

        # create central widget layout
        layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addRow("Directory:", DirectoryDialog())

        validator = QRegExpValidator(QRegExp(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,8}$"))
        line = QLineEdit(maxLength=8, objectName="QLineEdit_fname")
        line.setValidator(validator)
        layout.addRow("File name:", line)
        self.setLayout(layout)


class DirectoryDialog(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.line = QLineEdit()
        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.button = QPushButton("")
        self.button.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_DialogOpenButton))
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.browse_path)
        layout.addWidget(self.line, 0, 0, 1, 5)
        layout.addWidget(self.button, 0, 6, 1, 1)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def browse_path(self):
        path = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(
            self, "Select directory", str(Path.home()), QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly
        )
        if len(path) != 0:
            self.line.setText(path)


app = QApplication([])
window = CentralWidget()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

[image]

So, how can I fix the alignment, and more importantly, why did it mess up the alignment?

Comment: Your second code is identical to the first one, it simply contains another class definition, but that is never used. Ensure that you provide the valid code for the second example, as it's inconsistent with the image. Also, setting the span for unused columns in a grid layout is pointless, especially since you are using a single row, and the line edit will always be wider than a no-text button. If you want to ensure that the line edit grows if necessary, and you don't really need more than one row, just use QHBoxLayout and use `addWidget(widget, stretch=1)`.

Comment: @musicamante I messed up the copy/paste.. apologies. The correct snippet is now attached. I chose to use a QGridLayout because I wanted to have a very small button on the far right with a large line-edit on its left. Open to suggestions on how to do it better.

Comment: I can fix the alignment by having `DirectoryDialog` inherit from `QGridLayout`, but I don't understand why the inheritance from `QWidget` combined with `self.set_layout(..)` did not produce the correct render,

Comment: @Mathieu The layout will add default margins within a widget. Remove them like this: `layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)`.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Qt layouts always have a default "undefined" margin upon creation.

When set as managers of a widget, those margins become explicitly defined, following the current QStyle, which is about 10-12 pixels on all sides (the exact values depends on the OS or custom style, see the related pixel metrics in QStyle).

When directly added as *nested* layouts to a parent one, those margins remain undefined, so they default to 0 when finally added to another layout.

What you see in the second case is the *further* margin of the inner widget, because its layout is set on that widget; that margin is absent in case a layout is actually added instead of a container widget (because of the above reasons).

Note that while you could use a layout subclass for that purpose, it's normally discouraged, and an actual widget is preferable in any case.

For such custom components, it's usually better to *explicitly* set the layout margins to 0, so that they can be properly aligned as "unique widgets" to a parent layout.

Note that if you only need a single line of objects, using a grid layout is pointless, as the purpose of that layout is to show widgets along *both* rows and columns.

Setting spans for unused "cells" is also pointless: rows and columns of a grid layout do not represent actual "space" used on the layout, but just their logical indexes; if those rows and columns are not actually occupied by other widgets that have starts and spans in different cells, using a column span of 5 and adding a widget at the sixth column is fundamentally the same as adding them to columns 0 and 1.

If what you need is to ensure that a widget occupies more space than others, you must properly use [stretch factors](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html#stretch-factors), or eventually set the `Expanding` size policy for that widget.

Here is an improved version of your code, which also provides a better interface to access or set the path, including a dedicated signal when it is changed.

```py
class CentralWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setObjectName("central_widget")

        # create central widget layout
        layout = QFormLayout(self)
        layout.addRow("Directory:", DirectoryDialog())

        validator = QRegExpValidator(QRegExp(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,8}$"))
        line = QLineEdit(maxLength=8, objectName="QLineEdit_fname")
        line.setValidator(validator)
        layout.addRow("File name:", line)


class DirectoryDialog(QWidget):
    pathChanged = pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.line = QLineEdit()
        self.button = QPushButton()
        self.button.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_DialogOpenButton))
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.browse_path)

        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.line, stretch=1)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

        self.line.textChanged.connect(self.pathChanged)

    def path(self):
        return self.line.text()

    def setPath(self, path):
        self.line.setText(path)

    def browse_path(self):
        path = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(
            self, "Select directory", str(Path.home()), QFileDialog.ShowDirsOnly
        )
        if path:
            self.line.setText(path)
```